# WinRT: displaying video frames

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, winrt-async

What's the proper way to display video in WinRT?
I'm receiving video over RTP and I need to display video to some component or surface.
I can decode and/or convert video to YUV or any RGB format myself, I simply want to know what component I should use for video display.

Comment: Check `MediaElement`- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.aspx

Comment: Did you find a solution? Can you explain how you decode the stream yourself? Would be interesting for some people! :)

Comment: Yes, it was quite painful. The only suitable solution for me was using direct x. There are directx samples in sdk and that where I started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `MediaElement` to play the video. Check out MSDN sample for playing media.

[For Windows 8.1](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/basic-media-playback-003619be)

[For Windows 8](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-media-playback-sample-6d76261b)

If you want full fledged media player then check out [Player Framework: an open source component of the Microsoft Media Platform](http://playerframework.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I'm checkin that MediaElement thing and it looks that it's not suitable for my task. It expects some kind of file that it would play as a media player. But I have incoming RTP video that I decode myself. All I want is to show decoded video, but there is nothing in that MediaElement that does what I need. Any idea if there is anything else, or if I missed something in MediaElement?